# What is the probability that at least $ \ 7 \ $ out of $ \ 10 \ $ Students selected at random will be failed?

Tags: probability

If among  $ \ 500 \ $ students $  \ 55 \ \% \ $ passed and $ \ 45 \ \% \ $ failed . **What  is the probability that at least $ \  7  \ $ out of $ \ 10  \ $ Students selected at random will be failed ?**

**Answer**

The required probability is

$=\large \frac{\binom {10}{7} \times \binom{10}{3}}{\binom{500}{10}}+\frac{\binom {10}{8} \times \binom{10}{2}}{\binom{500}{10}}+\frac{\binom {10}{9} \times \binom{10}{1}}{\binom{500}{10}}+\frac{\binom {10}{10} \times \binom{10}{0}}{\binom{500}{10}} \ $

**I am not sure about the  answer ?**

**Can I use other formula like poisson trial merhod ?**

**Help me out .**

Comment: The answer you write down doesn't seem to make any use of the 55% and 45% data, so it's unlikely to be correct.

Comment: yes , so how can we solve this ?  I need idea

Comment: If $55\%$ of the $500$ students will pass, how many students in total will pass?  Well, $50\%$ of the students would be $250$ students, right?  And $50\%$ of the students is $0.5\cdot 500$ so.....   Okay, now that we know how many students passed, let us pick which specific seven of the students who passed were the ones who passed in our selection of ten students and which specific three of the students who failed were the ones who failed, etc...

Comment: can I use poisson sequence $ p^7 q^3 \times 10! +p^8 q^2 \times 10!+p^9 q \times 10!+p^{10} \ $ where $ p=55/100 , \ \ q=41/00 \ $

Comment: No because these are not independent events, they are very definitely dependent.  Just use direct counting techniques.  As an aside, you can perform what are called "sanity checks" for your answer to make sure that it could possibly make sense by checking certain properties.  For example, the formula you propose should give an answer of $100\%$ if you were to ask the question of finding the probability that at least 0 of the students failed, but $\binom{10}{0}\binom{10}{10}+\binom{10}{1}\binom{10}{9}+\dots+\binom{10}{10}\binom{10}{0}=\binom{20}{10}\ll\binom{500}{10}$

Comment: ok my last confusion , if it were asked that total students is say , $ \ 501 \ $ , then how would I proceed because in that case $ 55 \% \ \ of \ \ 501 \ $ would be a fraction ? Can i use then $ 100 \ $ as whole students

Comment: You are trying to grab a formula. It's better to grab ideas & concepts, and work your way through to a formula. @JMoravitz has got you started (except that it's seven failed and three passed, while JMo has it the other way around). Can you follow the reasoning to work out that probability of exactly seven failed and three passed? and then finish off the problem from there? without trying to apply formulas that you don't understand, just analyzing the problem logically, one piece at a time?

Comment: @JMoravitz I have revised my answer to include the exact solution. I would be surprised if, when calculated, they are very much different.

Answer (score 1):

You set $p=0.55$ and apply the binomial distribution. 
$= 0.45^{10}+ \binom {10}{1} (0.55)^1 (0.45)^9+ \binom {10}{2} (0.55)^2 (0.45)^8+ \binom {10}{3} (0.55)^3 (0.45)^7 $
This is a very good approximation.

To get an exact answer use the hypergeometric distribution as follows.
$=\large \frac{\binom {225}{7} \times \binom{275}{3}}{\binom{500}{10}}+\frac{\binom {225}{8} \times \binom{275}{2}}{\binom{500}{10}}+\frac{\binom {225}{9} \times \binom{275}{1}}{\binom{500}{10}}+\frac{\binom {225}{10}  }{\binom{500}{10}}$

Comment: If exact answers are feasible to calculate, it is generally expected that the exact answer be calculated instead of approximated.